# Bash, how to rename files in several folders from a script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell / bash script which will rename some file inside it's folder. I have this same file in several folders. I'd like to have one file which does all folders.

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in *.png; do
    # remove everything after the last '-' including the dash
    # and add the '.png' extension back
    newname="${name%-*}.png"
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: You will have to modify the script to loop through each file in multiple folders. This would be a recursive script.  We fortunately are not a script writing service.  What you want isn’t difficult, numerous scripts already exist, that loop the files each folders contained in a single folder.  Might do something else then you want but those scripts can be modified to do what you want

Comment: Possible way: use `for` command inside a `for` command (i.e. nested). First one changes folder name, second one changes file name.

Comment: Wouldn’t I need a second for loop, surely putting cd inside the for loop won’t allow all files to be renamed ?

Comment: @Ramhound can you guide me where I could find such scripts? Thanks.

Comment: First, have a look at the `prename` command (`rename` on Debian derivatives)

Comment: I’m using OS X on Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process files only in the top level of the directories (ie: one level deep), then you don't need recursion.

Both of these examples take a list of directories as arguments and rename only the files in those directories which match the more exclusive pattern: `*-*.png` (to avoid possible failures of the `mv` command).

## A script that does *NOT* change directory:

In this first script, inside the `for` loop, the variable `name` contains the directory path to the file in addition to the base filename.

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in "$@"
do
    for name in "$dir"/*-*.png
    do
        mv "$name" "${name%-*}.png"
    done
done
```

## A script that *DOES* change directory:

In this second script, inside the `for` loop, the `name` variable contains only the filename, because the current directory has been temporarily changed to the script argument.

The code between the parenthesis `(` and `)`, is executed in a *subshell* environment which means that changing the current directory, as well as variables set, will not be visible to the outer shell script, eliminating the need to change "back" to the original directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in "$@"
do
    (
        if cd "$dir"
        then
            for name in ./*-*.png
            do
                mv "$name" "${name%-*}.png"
            done
        fi
    )
done
```

## Notes About These Two Scripts:

The `"$@"` expands to the script's command line arguments.  The script will silently do nothing with no arguments.

The directory-name arguments can be any absolute path (`/path/to/dirx`) or relative path (`dirx`, `path/to/diry`, `.`, `..`, `../x/d1`, etc).

Messages will be printed on the standard error stream (stderr) by either `mv` or `cd` if a given directory does not exist, or if there are no `*-*.png` files in a directory. The script will continue processing subsequent directories.

The first line of these scripts can be `#!/bin/sh` instead of `bash` because this script uses none of the `bash` features, thus the more portable, posix compliant, and probably faster, `sh` can be used.  Few scripts require the extra features of the `bash` shell.  For these and other reasons `#!/bin/bash` is not generally recommended for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 for dir in *; do if cd $dir; then  for filename in *; do mv $filename "$filename.pdf"; done; cd ..; fi; done
```